# curl through authenticated proxy and authenticated http resource

Tags: rest, curl

I want to do a post (twitter in this case) with a oneliner.

If I don't have proxy

```
curl -u user:pass -d status="message" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

works perfectly.

But when I am behind a authenticated proxy it doesn't.

I had tryied:

```
curl -X proxy:port -U proxyUser:proxyPass -u user:pass -d status="message" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

That it jump me with an

> proxy do not support basic auth

So do you know what I am doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

[Cababunga's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4111223/185123), but they're missing another option: `--proxy-ntlm`.  Some proxies won't authorize correctly with `--proxy-anyauth`, so ideally you'll want to specify the authentication method that your proxy uses.  If you run `curl -v -U user:pass -x proxy:port --url http://www.google.com`, you should get something along the lines of the following:

- About to connect() to proxy [your proxy] port [your port] (#0)
- Trying [IP]...
- connected
- Connected to [your proxy] ([IP]) port [your port] (#0)
- Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.google.com:443
- Proxy auth using Basic with user '[user]'
- CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
- Host: www.google.com:443
- Proxy-Authorization: Basic [gibberish]
- User-Agent: curl/[ver] ([OS]) libcurl/[ver] OpenSSL/[ver] zlib/[ver]
- Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
- HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
- Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
- **Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM**

Add a flag for whatever you see in the Proxy-Authenticate parameter and you should be good to go.  In this example, you would add the `--proxy-ntlm` flag.

Answer (score 6):

You may be able to put the username/password in the URL for the authenticated resource to avoid having extra command line complications.

```
http://username:password@twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

also, the --proxy shortcut is a lowercase x, as cababunga pointed out.

```
curl -x proxyaddr:port -U proxyUser:proxyPass -u user:pass -d status="message" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `--proxy-digest` or `--proxy-anyauth`.
And I think to connect to proxy you should use lower case `-x` (not `-X`).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to perform this with the help of the Micah's answer here:

this is the command I got at the end to access a BitBucket repo:

```
curl  -u userBitbucket:PwdBitBucket -U userProxy:pwdProxy -x address_proxy:port:proxy --proxy-ntlm http://host:port/projects/project/repos/repo/browse/file
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using SOCKS v5 instead of v4:

```
$ curl --proxy socks5://proxyUser:proxyPass@proxy:port ...
```